# How can I change a Google+ (Plus) community from private to public?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

Is it possible to change the status of an existing Google+ community from "Private" to "Public"?

This screenshot shows that my community is set to "Private" and I couldn't find an option to change it yet.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

A *public* community can be changed from being fully open to requiring people request to join, but a *private* community cannot be made public, or vice versa.

([source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6320395))